# Error While Loading Shared Libraries (libGLU.so.1)

Tags: shared-library

I am trying to run Chamsys MagicQ on Ubuntu 12.10 with 64bit AMD processor.
This is what it tells me when I try to run the program.

> ./magicq: error while loading shared libraries: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object >file: No such file or directory

Here is the list of library dependencies for MagicQ:

> austin@ubuntu:~/magicq$ ldd ./magicq
>     linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7799000)
>     libGLU.so.1 => not found
>     libusb-0.1.so.4 => not found
>     libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => not found
>     libQt5OpenGL.so.5 => not found
>     libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
>     libQt5Network.so.5 => not found
>     libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
>     libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
>     libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib32/fglrx/libGL.so.1 (0xf7694000)
>     libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7679000)
>     libstdc++.so.6 => not found
>     libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf764d000)
>     libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf762e000)
>     libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7483000)
>     libXext.so.6 => not found
>     libatiuki.so.1 => /usr/lib32/fglrx/libatiuki.so.1 (0xf746c000)
>     libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7467000)
>     /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf779a000)

I know libGLU.so.1 is in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu as a "link to shared library (application/x-sharedlib)" Link target: "libGLU.so.1.3.1"
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 46):

Actually I couldn't find `libglu` package itself. What helped is:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa:i386
```

*Ubuntu 14.04 x64*

Comment: Also worked on Ubuntu 17.04. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: How did you get it working in 18.04?  Mine says Unable to locate package libglu1-mesa:i386 after apt-get update

Comment: for 18.04 this worked for me: `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa`

Answer (score 21):

I just needed to install this, without any 32-bit or 64-bit reference.

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1
```

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 17.10 (64-bit). Thanks!

Comment: This also worked for Sublime text in WSLg (Windows 10). Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I figured it out.  I had to install the 32-bit versions.

For anyone else who may have the same problem and is running a 64-bit operating system.  Find the packages that include the missing files and use:

> sudo apt-get install package:i386

Change "package" to the name of the package. Without the ":i386" it will install the 64 bit version only.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is reading this using Ubuntu 18.04, here's one way to search for the package to install. I got this error when trying to run [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) on a new Ubuntu 18.04 machine from a cloud computing instance. Here was the error, where I try to check if Blender 2.82a is installed correctly by printing out the version:

```
user@init-blender-test:~/blender-2.82a-linux64$ ./blender --version
./blender: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

To find the package to install, I did an `apt-file` search:

```
user@init-blender-test:~/blender-2.82a-linux64$ apt-file search libGL.so.1
libgl1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
libgl1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
nvidia-340: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
nvidia-340: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
primus-libs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus/libGL.so.1
virtualbox-guest-x11: /usr/lib/virtualbox/additions/libGL.so.1
virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe: /usr/lib/virtualbox/additions/libGL.so.1
```

See [this StackOverflow answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23021454/3287820). If `apt-file` isn't found, you may need to install it with `sudo apt install apt-file`.

Therefore, from the above, I see that `sudo apt install libgl1` can be used, and it fixed my error. Note that there are multiple packages that reference the missing file (`nvidia-340`, etc.) so you'll have to judge and test for yourself on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: this worked well, in my case libgl1 didn't work and it showed i needed to do `sudo apt install libglu1-mesa`

Answer (score 2):

i needed libGLU.so.1 for a game i wanted to play (The Fall) and got this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared
object file: No such file or directory
```

after a search i found a bug page where someone mentioned ia32-libs, and after installing that im up and runnig.

page i found:

*https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/891578*

Command i ran:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: That's the solution for older Ubuntu Distros ia32-lib is deprecated now. [Daniel](http://askubuntu.com/users/228344/daniel) in previous comment is correct for newer Distros. Well at least as an answer to the first error posted in OP.

Answer (score 1):

I had same kind of problem when i had deleted some of the files, i got them back using this command

```
sudo apt-get install libglew-dev libcheese7 libcheese-gtk23 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libcogl15 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-0
```

Hope it would work.

Answer (score 1):

This would help

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386  libglx-mesa0:i386  libglx0:i386  libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386
```

Comment: Why would this help?