# Installing tar.xz game (libGLU.so)

Tags: 16.04, sh

Unpacked the game, running `sh start.sh` results in:

```
start.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to start.sh
./hoi4: error while loading shared libraries: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
GAMEDIR=$(cd "${0%/*}" && echo $PWD)
cd "$GAMEDIR"
export LC_ALL=C
exec ./hoi4 "$@"
```

The expectation was that the question would be accepted as error specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error you're getting is because of the way you are trying to execute the script (and the rather strange way the script is written).

When a script is run, positional parameter `0` contains the name by which the script was invoked, e.g. `path/to/start.sh` - or simply `./start.sh` if it is called from the current directory. The parameter expansion syntax `${0%/*}` removes the shortest suffix from `$0` matching `/*` leaving (respectively) `path/to` or just `.` and the script then attempts to change to this directory - in other words, to the parent directory of `start.sh`

However, when you use `sh start.sh` (as well as executing the script using `sh` instead of the intended `/bin/bash`), `$0` equals `start.sh`. Since there's no matching `/`, `${0%/*}` doesn't remove anything from `$0`, resulting in the script trying to execute the command `cd start.sh` which obviously fails because `start.sh` is a file not a directory.

The solution is to execute the script the way the author presumably intended - that is, by ensuring it is executable

```
chmod +x start.sh
```

and then executing it directly, e.g.

```
./start.sh
```

Comment: Right one less error.

Comment: After: http://askubuntu.com/questions/386281/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libglu-so-1 for libglu issue.

I'm now getting libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast