# Failed to execute child process (No such file or directory)

Tags: command-line, 16.04, apt, package-management

I know this is a post for the DDNet forums, but no one over there seems to be able to figure this out. So I play a European game called DDNet, I'm trying to reinstall the game. But when I try to run it, I get an error saying: `Failed to execute child process /Insert/path/here (No such file or directory)`

Someone suggested that I install some dependencies so I installed the ones that they suggested: `sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev libfreetype6-dev`

But to no avail as I got the same error. So I installed another dependency:

`sudo apt install libsdl2-2.0-0`

But STILL I can't get it to work! I have the file set as an executable so that's not the problem. Can someone please help me?

Comment: And what Ubuntu version are you using? Did you update it to the latest packages? Hardware info?
Just a thought but would it make sense if you reinstalled the entire game, so it will resolve its own dependencies?

Comment: (1) Sorry I didn't specify. I'm using 16.04, All my packages are up to date. And I'm not quite sure what you mean by hardware info so here's what `cat /proc/cpuinfo` showed:

Comment: (2) `processor: 0
vendor_id: GenuineIntel
cpu family: 6
model: 55
model name: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N2840  @ 2.16GHz
cpu MHz: 1833.000
cache size: 1024 KB
fpu: yes
fpu_exception: yes
cpuid level: 11
wp: yes`

Also I am trying to reinstall the game, that was the point of the post, sorry I didn't mention I'll be sure to edit my post.

Comment: Does it actually say: `/Insert/path/here (No such file or directory)`? If so, create that directory/file and see what it will say next.

Comment: And are you using the 32 or 64 bit game on the likewise Ubuntu ?

Comment: I installed a new Ubuntu 16.40 VM in VMplayer, installed the latest DDnet 10.6 for Linux x86_64. I cd-ed into the extracted directory (did not change permissions!!) and ran ./DDnet, it gave an error saying it required: libSDL2-2.0, so I installed `sudo apt install libSDL2-2.0. I ran ./DDNet again and after some 'binds'messages I was presented the NEWS tab. That is where I stopped, assuming the game start was ok. Oh, I did see:  [17-05-19 16:33:22][client/version]: version does match (10.6) as final message after ending the game.

Comment: Some more output:willem@ubuntu:~/Downloads/DDNet-10.6-linux_x86_64$ ./DDNet
[17-05-19 16:33:16][engine]: running on unix-linux-amd64
[17-05-19 16:33:16][engine]: arch is little endian
[17-05-19 16:33:16][storage]: added path '$USERDIR' ('/home/willem/.teeworlds')
[17-05-19 16:33:16][storage]: added path '$DATADIR' ('data')
[17-05-19 16:33:16][storage]: added path '$CURRENTDIR' ('/home/willem/Downloads/DDNet-10.6-linux_x86_64')
[17-05-19 16:33:16][binds]: bound f1 (186) = toggle_local_console

Comment: The path says /home/hershel/Documents/DDNet-10.6, I am using the correct version (32-bit). I re-downloaded, and did NOT change the permissions. So I ran `cd /home/hershel/Documents/DDNet-10.6` then `./DDNet` and I got ` ./DDNet: error while loading shared libraries: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
I didn't get the same error as before but I'm not sure what to do to solve this.

Comment: and your Ubuntu is 32bit also? Tomorrow i will install a 32bits Ubu 16.04 and redo my test.

Comment: I right-clicked in the background of Nautilus and hit properties to see how much disk space I had left and got a similar error. I don't have the game you mentioned installed. My error has title "There was an error while getting the sharing information" and description "Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)". Clicking OK on the dialog doesn't make it go away, but clicking the close button on the top-left corner did. I repeated the process and this time it worked with not error. I had never seen this error before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I repeated the steps as per my earlier comment, but now in an Ubuntu 16.04 x86 VM in VMplayer. Again I had to `sudo apt install libSDL2-2.0` but then I was able to start the game:

[image]

So I don't know what you did, cleaned or otherwise removed that now causes the missing libGLU.so.1.

I now proved 2 times that the game starts on a fresh Ubuntu (with the exception of having to install libSDL2-2.0), so I stop further assistance and I end with advising you to do a clean install of Ubuntu on your computer.

Comment: I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu (I got a new computer so I had to reinstall it). I have libSLD2-2.0 installed. Proof: 
`$ sudo apt install libSDL2-2.0
[sudo] password for hershel: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-2.0-0' for regex 'libSDL2-2.0'
libsdl2-2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.0.4+dfsg1-2ubuntu2).`
I have a feeling you just don't know how to help me, because if you did then you would tell me how to fix the missing libGLU.so.1. you have the code so you should be able to help me

Comment: You did not mention anything about the missing libGLU.so.1 until after I finished installing the game the first time. You are right, I don know how to install each individual library there is in Ubuntu and frankly I don't want to know. I am savvy enough though to find out how to do it. Looking at your reputation index, I simply assumed you would too. But ok, here are 2 tips: first you run: `ldd ./DDNet`. This will show you all the libraries that your game depends on and their locations. So you may want to check if there are others missing too...

Comment: Next you take the error message (in this case: `error while loading shared libraries: libGLU.so.1: `) and Google it. I did and found: `https://askubuntu.com/questions/386281/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libglu-so-1`.  Now, as the library exists in my new Ubuntu I did not install it, but for your convenience here is the command: `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa:i386`. I trust you now know how to solve possible other missing items, so good luck.

Comment: No problem. Please post your solution/actions as an answer, so the question can be marked solved by the moderators.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install -f    
sudo apt update    
sudo apt upgrade    
sudo apt install *
```

Comment: Hello. How is this any answer to the question asked?